# VBA Ribbon and Sheetactivate

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have a workbook with personal Ribon Tab

======
"customTab"

## etc.

I would like this ribbon tab to be activated systematically when activating a sheet in the workbook, so that even if the user temporarily uses another ribbon tab, my custom tab is reactivated when switching to a sheet.

Despite all my research I haven't found a solution.

Thank you for help

Philippe

Comment: Do you have *any* VBA and/or *any* RibbonX so far? If so, it would make answering your question easier if you added them (the relevant parts ... if lengthy) to your question (ensure to add them as text, not as images).

Comment: Hint: set a reference to the ribbon-object in the `RibbonLoad` callback, then run *[Ribbon-object]*.ActivateTab("customTab") in the desired workbook event-handlers. Etc.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

yes I already have a ribbon whose code starts with:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
      onLoad="ribbonLoaded">
  <ribbon>
 <tabs>
 <tab id="customTab" label="DA2023" insertBeforeMso="TabHome">
  <group id="Navig" label="navigation">
```

For the VBA:

```
`Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI


'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub ribbonLoaded(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set myRibbon = ribbon
End Sub
```

`

And:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
 'Activate DA2023 ribbon
 On Error GoTo errhandle
 myRibbon.ActivateTab "customTab"
 Exit Sub
 errhandle:
 MsgBox "the DA2023 ribbon tab could not be displayed normally" &       Chr(13) & _
"If this error is continuous....." & Chr(13) & _
"Try to save the file, then open it again", vbCritical
 On Error GoTo -1

End Sub
```

BUT I have to deal with an error, because regularly calling the tab display causes an error.

Sincerely

THANKS